# JUnits 4 is running without any class level annotations? What is that I am missing here?

Tags: java, spring, junit

Most of the sample codes for implementing JUnits starts with importance of following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(MockServletContext.class)
```

However, I am able to run my test cases (annotated with @Test) without having these annotations at the top of the class.

What is that I have or am I missing something? Will these JUnits fail in some other environment due to missing annotations?

- Application : Spring/Hibernate
- Junits : Spring Junit 4
- OS : Windows 7
- IDE : Eclipse Neon
- Build Tool : Maven

I am using @Mock and @InjectMocks annotations for Autowiring of class properties.

Please assist.

Comment: probably those tests are not based out on spring's explicit runner and do not require the configuration either. Show us your tests code.

Comment: What build tool are you using? If you use maven then all in the test folder will be considered to be tests and thus will run as a tests. There is no need on that class level annotations if you are not using `Spring` functionalities in your tests (like autowiring beans in test class).

Comment: @TolegenIzbassar I am using Maven as build tool. If what you are saying is accurate, it explains the behavior. Can you share a link which can help me understand this more?

Comment: nullpointer : I am not allowed to share any code on public forums. However, I can tell that other than Spring DI, these tests don't need anything explicit. Also I am using @Mock for DI myself

Comment: You don't need a Spring for using `@Mock`: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/Mock.html

Comment: Dont read sample codes alone. Read good tutorials. Like this one: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit is a testing framework that is independent of Spring. This means tests by default don't use Spring.

JUnit uses a [Runner](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) to run tests. The class level annotation `@RunWith` tells JUnit that it should run the tests with a specific `Runner` instead of the default [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html) For example `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` adds additional features to JUnit that are helpful for testing  Spring applications.

For most tests you don't need a specific runner. The default runner provides enough features for most tests.

The annotations `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` are also not part of Spring. They belong to the mocking framework [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/). Mockito provides three ways of using them:

### MockitoRule

Add a [MockitoRule](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html) to your test.

```
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private YourClass something;

    @InjectMocks
    private AnotherClass sut;

    @Rule
    public final MockitoRule mockito = MockitoJUnit.rule();

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        //test code
    }
}
```

### Explicit initialization

Initialize the mocks in a `@Before` method with [MockitoAnnotations#initMocks](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html).

```
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private YourClass something;

    @InjectMocks
    private AnotherClass sut;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        //test code
    }
}
```

### MockitoJUnitRunner

Run your tests with the [MockitoJUnitRunner](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.9.0/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html). The runner has the disadvantage that there could only by one `Runner` and therefore you cannot combine it with another `Runner`.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)
public class ExampleTest {

    @Mock
    private YourClass something;

    @InjectMocks
    private AnotherClass sut;

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        //test code
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the default Runner provided with JUnit 4? Similarly is there any default SpringApplicationConfiguration as well?

Comment: The default runner is [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html)

Comment: Can you mention any one or 2 of those additional features to JUnit that (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) adds?

Comment: Upvoting here. I see no point in you providing two answers. This could have gone into one thing.

Comment: @Dish Sorry, but I don't know a lot about the Spring runner. Please have a look at its source code.